# Как передать переменную jinja в обработчик события на javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja

Мне нужно передать переменную jinja в обработчик события onclick, который создаёт яндекс карту по id и center

```html
{% set id = 10 %}
{% set center = [50, 50] %}
<button onclick="createMap('ymap_' + {{ id }}, {{ center }})"></button>
```

Такой код не работает, я получаю такие ошибки:

```js
Property assignment expected.
',' expected.
Argument expression expected.
Property assignment expected.
',' expected.
```

[image: Ошибки в коде]

Ошибки перечислены в таком порядке, в каком они подсвечены на картинке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы исправить эти ошибки, нужно обернуть значения переменных id и center в кавычки, чтобы они были правильно переданы в функцию createMap как строки.

Вот как должен выглядеть исправленный код:

```
{% set id = 10 %}
{% set center = [50, 50] %}
<button onclick="createMap('ymap_' + '{{ id }}', '{{ center }}')"></button>
```

Обратите внимание, что также нужно добавить кавычки вокруг значений переменных id и center, чтобы они были правильно интерпретированы как строки.

В качестве альтернативы, вы также можете использовать функцию escapejs из Jinja2 для корректной экранировании переменных:

```
<button onclick="createMap('ymap_' + {{ id|escapejs }}, {{ center|escapejs }})"></button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает!